# How can I convert full-width characters to half-width characters (and vice versa)?

Tags: character-encoding

Here is my simple problem, how can I convert half-width to full-width from the command line. I thought this would be built-in my `iconv` command line, but I did not find anything here:

```
$ iconv  -l | grep -i full
-> nothing
$ iconv  -l | grep -i half
-> nothing
```

Typical input would be:

```
$ echo -n "Ａb９８７６５４３２１０" | iconv -f utf8 -t utf16be | hexdump -C
00000000  ff 21 00 62 ff 19 ff 18  ff 17 ff 16 ff 15 ff 14  |.!.b............|
00000010  ff 13 ff 12 ff 11 ff 10                           |........|
00000018
```

Comment: Since the convertible subset is pretty small, it might be simpler to just build two sets yourself and use standard tools to translate from one to other and back. See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/64708420/2072269

Comment: For those specifically, on a GNU system at least, you can use `iconv -t ASCII//translit`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the `uconv` utility from the ICU tools (`icu-devtools` package on Debian-based OSes):

```
$ echo 'Ａb９８７６５４３２１０' | uconv -x Fullwidth-Halfwidth
Ab9876543210
```

(beware it also converts characters that are normally full-width such as ones in the Korean or Japanese scripts to their half-width representation).

Change to `Halfwidth-Fullwidth` for the reverse.

If not and you're only interested in converting the full-width variants of the ASCII printable characters:

```
$ echo 'Ａb９８７６５４３２１０' | perl -C -pe 'y/\x{ff01}-\x{ff5e}/!-~/'
Ab9876543210
```

Or also converting U+3000 (ideographic space) to ASCII space:

```
$ echo 'Ａb９８７６５４３２１０' | perl -C -pe 'y/\x{3000}\x{ff01}-\x{ff5e}/ !-~/'
Ab9876543210
```

```
curl -s https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt | grep '<wide>'
```

Will reveal a few extra that are the full-width variants of some non-ASCII characters, which you can add to the list.

```
perl -C -pe 'y/\x{3000}\x{ff01}-\x{ff60}\x{ffe0}-\x{ffe6}/ !-~\x{2985}\x{2986}\xa2\xa3\xac\xaf\xa6\xa5\x{20a9}/'
```

(and searching for `<narrow>` will show the half-width variants of some normally full-width characters, but that's a large list and with non-contiguous ranges so adding those would render the expression much larger).

On some systems, you may be able to do the same with `tr` if in the C.UTF-8 locale, [not with current versions of GNU `tr` unless patched by your OS vendor](/q/389615).

```
$ uname
FreeBSD
$ echo 'Ａb９８７６５４３２１０' | LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 tr $'\u3000\uff01-\uff5e' ' !-~'
Ab9876543210
```

(also assuming a shell with support for zsh's `$'\uXXXX'`).

For the reverse conversion, just change the `y/from/to/` to `y/to/from/`.

`perl` also has an interface to the Unicode data in its `Unicode::UCD` module, so you could also do:

```
perl -C -MUnicode::UCD=charprop -pe '
  s{\p{Decomposition_Type: Wide}}{
    $cache{$&} //= charprop(ord($&), "Decomposition_Mapping")
  }ge'
```

Though it's quite slow even if mitigated here by the use of caching. See `perldoc perluniprops` and `perldoc Unicode::UCD` for details.

Or using the [NFKD decomposition](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) for those characters that have a *wide* decomposition type:

```
perl -MUnicode::Normalize=NFKD -C -pe 's/\p{Dt=Wide}/NFKD$&/ge'
```

If it's to convert to ASCII, on GNU systems at least, `iconv -t ASCII//translit` would also convert those (and more characters to their closest ASCII character¹ representation)

```
$ echo 'Ｓｔéｐｈａｎｅ' | iconv -t ASCII//translit
Stephane
```

Obviously, there's no way to do the reverse.

In any case, here, it's not conversion of the same character from charset to charset you want to do, but some form of transliteration from some characters to other characters.

`iconv -l` like `uconv -l` lists the supported encodings/charsets. `uconv -L` lists the transliterators. GNU `iconv` only has that `//translit` which gives possible approximation if the character doesn't exist in the target charset (besides `//ignore` which just discards them instead).

---

<sup>¹ or character**s** like in `æ` -> `ae` or `ﬃ` -> `ffi` which by the way don't have full-width forms but have once approximated; for instance, you might want to convert `aﬃx` to `ａｆｆｉｘ` rather than `ａﬃｘ` when converting to full-width which none of the solutions mentioned here handle.</sup>

Comment: Two things: 1. Congrats on finding `uconv` for me. 2. I discovered `uconv -x 'hex-any; any-name'` and this is time for me to ditch `iconv` !

Comment: Compare `printf %s '' | uconv -x Any-Hex` with `printf %s '' | uconv -x Any-Hex/C` though. I'd avoid the `Hex` alone variants.

Comment: Note to self `uconv` does not support _traditional_ shift-jis, eg. `$ echo -n '\' | uconv -f shift-jis -t utf8`

Comment: Try `uconv -f cp943 -t utf-8` instead (see `uconv -l` showing 3 different variants of Shift_JIS)